# Arrange icons in the middle of table row

Tags: html, css, html-table

Hi i need a table like in below image

[image]

but i dont know how to arrange images like that.So this is the current code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table id="tab" border="1">
<tr>
  <td><img align ="center" border="0" src="/images/cam.jpg"  width="15px" height="15px"></td>
  <td><img align ="center" border="0" src="/images/gal.jpg"  width="15px" height="15px"></td>
  <td><img align ="center" border="0" src="/images/chat.jpg"  width="15px" height="15px"></td>
</tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

check here :http://pastebin.com/HLPdDNyg

Comment: Any CSS you tried so far? What's your exact issue?

Comment: tried but not working the correct way

Comment: Why do you use a `table` for that?

Answer (score 1):

try this one,

```
table
{
    border:1;
    width:500px;
}
td
{
     border:0;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    text-align:center;
}
td img
{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9AxmR/2/

Comment: can i ask one more doubt?

Comment: here if i click "image" then <td><a href="#" >some image</a>   it wll do avtion  .but i need something like where ver i click insde that <td></td> have to do that action

Comment: sorry i cant get u.. if u want some other thing  please update ur question wat u want

Comment: i will give one Video file,https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6caVk8MnBVaZGlYdzBWTG1SQlk/edit?usp=sharing           in this u can see when i click the icon one division (back color) is cpoming up ryt?? and whenver i click outside it wont come becoz ony that i con have <a href="#"></a> link.my question is is there any way to do coding so i click inside that <td></td> the division (black) will come instead of clicking icon??

Comment: am getting that list in vertical instead of horizondal

Comment: set the width to ul and then check if still like that give the site url or jsfiddle

Comment: i need some help from  u

Comment: to design some pages  nnaavveenn35@gmail.com ping me

Answer (score 1):

*[Live demo](http://jsbin.com/ewOgUwU/3/edit)*

```
<table id="tab" >
<tr>
  <td><img src=""></td>
  <td><img src=""></td>
  <td><img src=""></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
#tab{
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
#tab td{
  background:#eee;
  width:100px;
  text-align:center;
  padding:0 15px;
}
#tab td img{
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: when i tried ur code to make responsive then its not showing in correct order may i know y?